# Accessing class information from another class without passing it

Tags: c++, class

Say I have a framework that contains a `jWorld` class which contains useful information about my physics environment (gravity, etc) and I have a `jPhysicsObject` that will use this information.  Is there any way for `jPhysicsObject` to access `jWorld` information without passing `jWorld` every time I want to make a relevant change to `jPhysicsObject`?

Comment: Static members and methods. The moniker "world" almost implies this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing by reference (const reference is preferable).

Another idea is to implement a global instance, such as a Singleton.

Otherwise use static methods and static data members.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, pass it one time as reference (if jWorld shoudn`t change for an object) or as a pointer to the constructor of jPhysicsObject (for safety reason you can use shared_ptr for pointer)

Answer (score 1):

Just have the constructor of the `jPhysicsObject` take a `jWorld` object as a reference. And then query it when you need to query it.

```
class jWorld {
    public:
        jWorld();
};  

class jPhysicsObject {
    public:
        jPhysicsObject(jWorld const & world): mWorld(world);

    private:
        jWorld const & mWorld;
};  

int main() {
    jWorld world;
    jPhysicsObject object(world);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option to go will be to use the Observable design pattern. Your jPhysicsObject will be an observer while your jWorld will be ovservable. jPhysicsObject will add itself as an observer to jWorld. When something changes in jWorld, jPhysicsObject will be notified about it. This way you will have a loosely coupled architecture which will come in handy if you are planning on introducing other objects that will listen to changes in jWorld class.

Here is a code snippet that will help you to get started on the Observer pattern:

```
//IObserver.hpp
#pragma once
#include <memory>

template <class T>
class IObserver
{
public:
    virtual ~IObserver() {};
    virtual void Notify(T data) = 0;
protected:
};



//Observable.hpp
#pragma once

#include "IObserver.hpp"
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

template<class T>
class Observable
{
public:
    void NotifyObservers(T data)
    {
        for (auto o : m_observers)
        {
            o.Notify(data);
        }
    }

    void AddObserver(std::shared_ptr<IObserver<T>> &obs)
    {
        m_observers.push_back(obs);
    }

    void RemoveObserver(std::shared_ptr<IObserver<T>> &obs)
    {
        m_observers.remove(obs);
    }

private:
    std::list<std::shared_ptr<IObserver<T>>> m_observers;
};
```

Comment: I'm afraid this delves a little too far into the language for me at the moment, but thank you for bringing `#pragma once` to my attention -- I'd not seen it before.

Comment: @theStandard #pragma once makes sure the same header file only gets included once in the source file. It's a Microsoft thing. If you prefer not to use it, you can have your header file contents in a "#ifndef H_FILE #define H_FILE #endif" block

Comment: I know what it does.  Unfortunately I'm stuck on linux for a while so it's not really an issue, but I don't mind normal include guards.